# Converting QColor into QString without losing alpha value

Tags: c++, qt, colors, alpha, qcolor

Consider the code:

```
QColor m_color = QColor(255,255,255,0); //alpha is 0
QString m_str = m_color.name(); //#ffffff
```

`m_color` is a transparent color with alpha value 0. Now I want to convert this color value into `QString` without losing transparency (alpha value).

`QColor.name()` converts it to `#ffffff` which is 'white' color whereas I want transparent color. What should I do?

Comment: Select `name()` _function name_ & press `F1` key shall always help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: Just use the second overload of [`QColor::name`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#name-1):

```
QString m_str = m_color.name(QColor::HexArgb); //#00ffffff
```

Note: Please check the Qt documentation first for such questions - it is barely worth asking on STOF...